# Macro para verificar si deja de repetirse algo inserte una linea y borre lo repetido

Tags: excel, vba, macros

[[image: EJEMPLO1]

hola tengo un dilema no tengo ni la mas minima idea de como hacerlo quiero quitar los repetidos  pero que inserte una linea cuando se dejen de repetir

Comment: Pero ¿has probado ya algo? ¿tienes un ejemplo de eso que ya has probado? O no tienes nada y necesitas el código completo?. Te recomiendo leas esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Ordena()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim uf, uff, uff1, r1, r3, r, conta, k1, co, fila, fila2, conta1 As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim sum As Currency
'determines last row with data
uf = Sheets("NOBORRAR").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
uc = Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells("1," & Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Address(False, 
False)
uc = Mid(uc, 1, 1)
r = 1
conta = 0
fila = 2
fila2 = 2
sum = 0
conta1 = 0
x = 2
'Antes de ordenar, elimina filas vacias
uff = Sheets("NOBORRAR").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
While x <= uff
If Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(x, 1) = Empty Then
    Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    x = x - 1
GoTo aqui:
End If
x = x + 1
aqui:
uff = Sheets("NOBORRAR").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Wend

While Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(1, r) <> Empty And conta = 0
    If Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(1, r) = "N" Then
        k = Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(1, r).Address(False, False)
        co = Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(1, r).Column
        conta = 1
    End If
r = r + 1
Wend

k1 = Mid(k, 1, 1)

'will help determine ranges to sort data
    r1 = k & ":" & k1 & uf
    r3 = "A1:" & uc & uf
'sorts the data
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NOBORRAR").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NOBORRAR").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(r1) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NOBORRAR").Sort
    .SetRange Range(r3)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

While Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila, co) <> Empty
dato1 = Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila, co)

While Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila, co) <> Empty And conta1 = 0
  dato2 = Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila2, co)
  If dato1 = dato2 Then
  sum = sum + Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila2, 7).Value
  Else
   Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila2, co).EntireRow.Insert
   Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila2, co).EntireRow.Insert
   Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila2, co) = "SUMATORIA"
   Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila2, co).Select
   Selection.Font.Bold = True
   Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila2, 7) = sum
   Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila2, 7).Select
   Selection.Font.Bold = True
   Selection.Font.Bold = True
   
       With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With

   conta1 = 1
  End If
fila2 = fila2 + 1
Wend

fila = fila2 + 1
fila2 = fila
conta1 = 0
sum = 0
     
Wend
'Sheets("NOBORRAR").Cells(fila2, 7) = "=SUMIF(A:G,"SUMATORIA",G:G)"
   
End Sub
```

lo resolvi con esto